# How to scale and align figures and tables in LaTex in a 3x2 grid like manner?

Tags: tables, minipage

I'm writing a paper with LaTex and I would really like to get the following setup of figures and tables:

[image]

I'm not a LaTex expert so I thought maybe wiser people here might have good ideas how to implement this? Your help would save hours and hours of googling ;) Thank you

Comment: what you try so far? here on site are plenty similar questions with good answers ...

Comment: Excellent, can you direct me to those answers please? :) I did not try because I do not know how to do it. If I knew I wouldn't ask it. I mean I'm not sure how to even start. Should I use minipages? Something else? or what? Are there some scaling issues, how do the images and tables scale w.r.t each other? and so and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

solution with use of `subfig` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\hfil
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\hfil
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\hfil
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
\caption{2 x 3 grid of images}
    \label{fig:my figure}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

solution with use `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{2 x 3 grid of images}
    \label{fig:my figure}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

both solution gives the same result:

[image]

in case, that you like to have sub figures numbering in order of columns, than you the simplest solution is enclosed sub figures or sub floats in table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{CC}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
&
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{2 x 3 grid of images}
    \label{fig:my figure}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Zarko appreciate it. Three minor questions: 1) Can you swap the identifier places so that the first column of figures would have identifiers a,b,c and second d,e,f? 2) Can you simply replace the figures with tables in the subfloats? 3) Does this solution automatically scale all the grid elements to same size no matter if they're tables or figures?

Comment: 1), this is possible, but the code is not so simple and clear; 2)  you can use tables in `subfloat` or use `subtable`, however in this case use of `table` environment is sensible.

Comment: excellent, thank you. About your answer to question 1), so how do you do it? Do you happen to have a reference example? Thanks =)

Comment: @jjepsuomi, see edited answer